# Search Range in Disparity Map

Tags: c++, opencv, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

While calculating disparity map from two stereo images using OpenCv stereoSBM function how can we set up the search range and what implications does it have on disparity map and depth values so generated.

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation?

Comment: @BalajiR http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d85/classcv_1_1StereoSGBM.html. I went through this link but couldn't  find any parameters related to it.